# How to fix "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" for this code as it was working a few weeks ago?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting this error pop up when I try to run the code below:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/benja/PycharmProjects/Project12/random.py", line 2, in 
<module>
import random
File "C:\Users\benja\PycharmProjects\Project12\random.py", line 8, in 
<module>
random.random()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import random


uF=[]
for i in range(1, 10):
    for x in range(1):
        random.random()
print(uF)
```

I've tried reinstalling pycharm and python but it still doesn't seem to want to work even though it was working only a week ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rename your file away from `random.py` as to not collide with the inbuilt random module.

I'm guessing a few weeks ago your file was not named this way.